# Express the 2-cell adjunction

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

[image]I am trying to express the surface below as a 2 cell adjunction. If we transfer the shape as planar as drawn in the diagram I think that should get it, but I am not sure how can I do this rigorously. I think that shape is actually homeomorphic to 2-torus ?

Comment: If you express the surface non-rigorously with a picture, then the best description you're going to get of transferring it to the plane will be a similarly non-rigorous picture. And no, it's not homeomorphic to the 2-torus, which has empty boundary, whereas the surface you have depicted has nonempty boundary.